# How does the user-mode kernel in UML interface with the underlying kernel on the host

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, user-mode-linux

In user mode linux (UML) a trace thread annuls system calls made by the user-space process and redirects them to a kernel running in user-space. Now at some point this userspace kernel would require assistance of the host OS. How does the user-mode kernel call the underlying host kernel, Is it just normal system calls? Or does it use some kind of IOCTL mechanism or something else?

Answer (score 2):

I found an very simple explanation of UML design [here](http://www.cse.psu.edu/~buu1/teaching/spring06/slides/uml.ppt). It may be useful for you.

> UML constructs it using ptrace system call tracing mechanism.
>
> 1. When a process in user space, its system called are intercepted by ptrace.
> 2. When it is in the kernel, no interception. When a process executes a
>      system call or receives signal, the tracing thread forces the process to run in the kernel.
> 3. After the transition, the process state is restored and it continues.
>
> System call virtualization
>
> 1. By switching the user and kernel and system calls interception
> 2. Note: the system call must be annulled in the host kernel.
> 3. The process state is preserved.
> 4. When the system call is complete, the process obtains the returned value in its saved registers and returned to user mode.

Also, this article explains [System call virtualization using ptrace](http://www.csee.wvu.edu/~katta/uml/x375.html) with the following picture.

http://www.csee.wvu.edu/~katta/uml/graphics/vsyscall.jpg. The red line represents the normal syscall procedure.

Comment: In the above diagram, is "Kernel stack" the user-space running kernel or the host kernel?

Comment: @syed, the user-space running kernel.

Comment: Links are broken